# Find all possible Jordan canonical forms of $A$, where $(A-2I)^3(A+2I)^2=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

> A $5\times 5$ matrix $A$ satisfies the equation $(A-2I)^3(A+2I)^2=0$. Assuming there are at least $2$ linearly independent eigenvectors for $2$, write all possible Jordan canonical forms.

My Question:

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $2$ and $-2$. If we know the number of linearly independent eigenvectors for $2$, can we determine the number of linearly independent eigenvectors for $-2$?

Comment: the eigenvectors of $2$ and $-2$ are linearly independent. i don't know what else you can conclude.

Comment: Can't you use the Cayley Hamilton theorem to find out the multiplicity of the eigenvalues? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-HamiltonTheorem.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: If we denote by $J_k(\lambda)$ the Jordan block of eigenvalue $\lambda$ and size $k \times k$, then both
$$
J_1(2) \oplus J_1(2) \oplus J_1(2) \oplus J_1(-2) \oplus J_1(-2)
\qquad\text{and} \qquad
J_1(2) \oplus J_1(2) \oplus J_1(2) \oplus J_2(-2)
$$
satisfy the equation $(A - 2I)^3 (A + 2I)^2 = 0$, and both have three linearly independent eigenvectors of eigenvalue $2$, but the first has two linearly independent eigenvectors of eigenvalue $-2$ and the second has only one.

Comment: why not $J_1(2)+J_2(2)+J_2(-2),J_1(2)+J_2(2)+J_1(-2)+J_1(-2)?$

Comment: Ok so the answer must be the union of Travis's and abel's answers. Isn't it?

Comment: No reason to prefer one over the other. Of course, it's sufficient to give a single example to show that it's not enough to know the number of linearly independent eigenvectors of eigenvalue $2$.